# 'Function not defined' error in script w/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I'm getting a "function not defined" Javascript error with the following code, which uses jQuery:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>  

<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

function log_in() {
   document.write('Logging in ... ');
   $.post('process_ajax.php', { 'action' : 'log in' }, function(data) {
      document.write(data);
      create_new_story();
   });
}

function create_new_story() {
   document.write('Creating new story ... ');
   $.post('process_ajax.php', { 'action' : 'create story' }, function(data) {
     document.write(data);
   });
}

</script>

</head>

<body onload="log_in()">
Processing...<br>
</body>

</html>
```

Here's the PHP script it's calling (for testing purposes):

```
<?

die("Page opened.<br>");

?>
```

The first function called -- log_in() -- works fine, but I get this error:

"Error: create_new_story is not defined"

And that function never gets executed.

I'm sure I'm missing something simple.  Can I get a new pair of eyes to find it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only call `document.write` while the page is still loading.

You cannot call it later, or it will blow away the existing page.

Instead, you should use jQuery's `.append` method.

Answer (score 0):

When you call document.write() after the DOM is ready then it actually *replaces* the entire page with the argument to document.write().

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/_rsp/S38rP/).